# Kafka Mirror Maker not Replicating topics when source and destination clusters are not in the same configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

We have setup Mirror Maker to replicate topics between two kafka clusters when the source and destination setup are different(source= 2 servers , destination = 3 servers).
when starting the MirrorMaker its throws the following error:
"Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)" and no replication between the clusters.
we used MirrorMaker version 2.

Can anyone please provide some suggestion why it is not working as expected?

Comment: Does it work if you use the same cluster size, e.g. 2 servers for both source and destination?

Comment: Please show your configuration files. The error is suggesting that that min ISR for the destination cluster isn't being met

Answer (score 2):

Mirrormaker 2.0 documentation is only coming in the new 2.5.0 release - which makes setting up Mirrormaker 2.0 frustratingly hard. Basically I think you would need to set your replication factors (which defaults to 3 in Kafka) to 2 as this is your minimum for one cluster. These are the config values you probably need to set:

- checkpoints.replication.factor
- heartbeats.replication.factor
- offset-syncs.replication.factor
- config.storage.replication.factor
- offset.storage.replication.factor
- status.storage.replication.factor
- replication.factor
- offsets.replication.factor
- transaction.state.log.replication.factor

You can set these in the MM2 config file.